# SharePoint InputFormTextBox only returning <div></div>

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have been trying to use SharePoint:InputFormTextBox as Rich Text Editor in my SharePoint webpart. It works fine only in IE, but that isn't my issue right now. The issue is when I try to get the Text Box's value using a Request.Form, it just returns a open and close div tag. Any help will be appreciated to point me in the right direction in solving my problem. Also, I am creating the InputFormTextBox in my .cs class dynamically, not in the aspx side.

Comment: I solved it after just looping through all of the Request.Form variables being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the request.form collection helped me solve my problem.